# Stringificaton operator unexpectedly called

Tags: perl, operator-overloading

I am debugging [a test](https://metacpan.org/source/NUFFIN/MPEG-Audio-Frame-0.09/t/04-tie.t) in [MPEG::Audio::Frame](https://metacpan.org/pod/MPEG::Audio::Frame). If I run this test, I get:

```
$ cpan -g MPEG::Audio::Frame
$ tar zxvf MPEG-Audio-Frame-0.09.tar.gz
$ cd MPEG-Audio-Frame-0.09
$ perl Makefile.PL
$ make
$ perl -I./blib/lib t/04-tie.t 
1..5
ok 1 - use MPEG::Audio::Frame;
ok 2 - 'tie' isa 'MPEG::Audio::Frame'
Not a HASH reference at blib/lib/MPEG/Audio/Frame.pm line 273, <DATA> line 1.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 just after 2.
```

I narrowed down the problem to the following minimal example:

```
package My::Module;
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use overload '""' => \&asbin;

sub asbin {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{binhead}  # $self is not yet a hash, so execution stops here.
}

sub TIEHANDLE {
    bless \$_[1], $_[0]
}

sub READLINE {}

sub read {
    say "reading..";
    my $pkg = shift;
    my $fh = shift || 0;  # Why is the stringification operator called here?
}

package main;
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

tie *FH, 'My::Module', *DATA;
My::Module->read(\*DATA); 
<FH>;

__DATA__
abc
```

Why is the stringification operator called for the statement `My::Module->read(\*DATA)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shift || 0` will want to coerce the argument in `shift` to a scalar. There is no boolify or numify function overloads defined for `My::Module`, so Perl will use your stringify function.

To avoid evaluating the object in scalar context, you could rephrase it as

```
my $fh  = @_ ? shift : 0;

$fh = shift;
$fh = 0 unless ref($fh) || $fh;
```

or define a `bool` function overload.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why [this line](https://metacpan.org/source/NUFFIN/MPEG-Audio-Frame-0.09/lib/MPEG/Audio/Frame.pm#L194) `my $fh = shift || return undef` worked fine with earlier perls (since the test must have passed when the author wrote them)?

Comment: Better to say "boolean context", since even in your suggested code, it is used in scalar context.

Comment: Added [bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=43015)